# How to reset to identity the "current transformation matrix" with some CGContext function?

Tags: cocoa-touch, matrix, core-graphics

I'm doing a series of translations and rotations on the CTM and at some point I need to reset it to identity before going further with transformations.

I can't find any proper way to do it (obviously, there should have been a function named CGContextSetCTM or so) and since efficiency is the key, I don't want to use CGContextSaveGState/CGContextRestoreGState...

Comment: Can you clarify your reason for needing the current context scaled to identity? This seems like an unlikely operation, and there may be a smarter way to do your drawing at the scale and translation you wish.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Get current transformation matrix via [CGContextGetCTM](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextGetCTM), invert it with [CGAffineTransformInvert](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformInvert) and multiply the current matrix by the inverted one (that's important!) with [CGContextConcatCTM](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextConcatCTM). CTM is now identity.

Comment: Seems to be a viable workaround but it's terribly inefficient. I don't understand why Apple is not exposing any function to directly reset the matrix...

Comment: @EightyEight: Probably because Apple wants the transformation matrix to remain modifiable based on transformations further up the chain, and wants devs to write code does the right thing in these situations. Example: what if Apple (hypothetically) wanted to implement a UI for games that shows them reduced in size while running, like the tiled webpages in Safari's tab view? What would happen if a dev decided to reset the transformation matrix in their drawing code? _It wouldn't “just work”, it would look like distorted crap, that's what._

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Just to point out: Apple would use Core Animation in *that* specific case. ;)

Comment: @IvanVučica How does Core Animation get the graphics hardware to do what it wants to do?  My guess is transformation matrixes via OpenGL and/or Core Graphics.

Comment: @IvanVučica Actually… Core Animation doesn't do any kind of drawing on its own; it's just a higher-level library that simply makes some graphic tasks (esp. animation) easier than talking to a graphics library directly (source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Yes. That doesn't mean Apple would not use Core Animation in that specific case. Any Core Graphics drawing would, in case you want to rescale stuff, be directed to a `CALayer` which would be rescaled. Because scaling an already painted texture is far, far quicker than redrawing the bitmap content itself. Hence, messing with the Quartz CTM would mess up contents of texture (represented by the `CGContext`) stored in `CALayer`, but not outside of that individual layer.

Comment: @IvanVučica How does the CALayer get the graphic data it represents to the graphics hardware (and thus, onto the screen)?

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson It creates a `CGContext` that it passes on to its own `-drawInContext:` and its delegate's `-drawLayer:inContext:`. Once the content is drawn in the context, it is uploaded to that layer's texture. In my implementation of Core Animation, I use a `CGBitmapContext` and then upload the resulting RGBA data to the texture. Apple does similar things; sure, they do it better, faster, and what they do is way more advanced -- but this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 4):

The save/restore operations are probably a single memory copy of a memory region comparable to the size of the identity matrix (twice or thrice the size). It might only happen for the save operation. Consider that this is probably not much slower than a nop FUNCTION call. Each graphic operation is in the scale of several multiplication operation and I'm guessing this happens more than once in your code for each save/restore cycle. The time of one graphic operation is probably larger than a single save/restore cycle.

Comment: On iPhone 6: Save + restore is about 630 nanoseconds. Save + flip CTM + restore about 670 nanoseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Note that inverting the current CTM with CGAffineTransformInvert does not work if your current CTM is singular.

The obvious case is if previously CGContextConcatCTM was performed with matrix CGAffineTransformMake(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).