# Issue rotating a UIView object using Core Animation and blocks

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I have a problem with a UIView-subclass object that I am rotating using Core Animation in response to a UISwipeGesture.

To describe the context: I have a round dial that I have drawn in CG and added to the main view as a subview.
In response to swipe gestures I am instructing it to rotate 15 degrees in either direction dependent on whether it;s a left or right swipe.

The problem that it will only rotate each way once. Subsequent gestures are recognised (evident from other actions that are triggered) but the animation does not repeat. I can go left once then right once. But trying to go in either direction multiple times doesn't work. Here's the relevant code, let me know your thoughts...

```
- (IBAction)handleLeftSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    if ([control1 pointInside:[sender locationInView:control1] withEvent:nil]) 
    {
    //updates the display value
    testDisplay.displayValue = testDisplay.displayValue + 0.1;
    [testDisplay setNeedsDisplay];

    //rotates the dial
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        CGAffineTransform  xform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians(+15));
        control1.transform = xform;
        [control1 setNeedsDisplay];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I'm going to look into the answer below, but just to complicate things further... THe UIView dial has a shadow. Rotating the view also rotates the shadow. I guess I need a way to restore the position on the CTM (transform matrix) back by 15 degrees and redrawing it to avoid the shadow issue? I don't know how to set the alter the CTM outside of the drawRect method of the view. I can't refer to the graphics context of the view out in the view controller. I think. I could be wrong...

Comment: So are you trying to rotate the dial but not the shadow?  And are the dial and shadow in the same view?

Comment: yes to both questions. I could put another view under the dial with the shadow so it's hidden except for the shadow and use the counter method we discussed. Its just that I can't believe there isn't some way to reset the transform matrix. I've been through documentation but can;t see anything. Perhaps it's just something that I need to accept.

Comment: That is one workaround, this may be of interest to you though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469505/how-to-reset-to-identity-the-current-transformation-matrix-with-some-cgcontext

Comment: thats an interesting thread. My worry is that they discuss CGGetContext which I can only do from inside the drawRect method of the view. I need to do it from the main view controller. Hmmm... I'm going to sleep on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGAffineTransform  xform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians(+15));

Do you keep a total of how far the rotation is.  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation are not additive.  Only the most recent is used.  So you are setting it to 15 each time, not 15 more each time.

Comment: Further: although reading the rotation back via the `control1.transform` property is appealing (e.g. implicitly via `CGAffineTransformRotate`), there's a risk of rounding errors accumulating over time. So it's probably better to track the angle as an instance variable and continue to use `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`.

Comment: Ahh so you mean each time I trigger a rotation increment a counter and rotate by 15 * counter?

Comment: That would be one way to go about it.  And no problem.

Comment: I've encountered a problem, see comment above on original post... thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a super simple example of rotating a view cumulatively.  This rotates the view by 180 degrees each button press.

```
    - (IBAction) onRotateMyView: (id) sender
    {

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
          myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2*rotationCounter);
     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        //No nothing
     }];

     ++rotationCounter;
}
```